# Which user is logged in, with likewise and Ubuntu12.4?

Tags: python, active-directory, ubuntu-12.04

I need to know which user is logged in my computer but with likewise package installed it does not work.
I've used the following commands
who
users
psutil.get_users()[with python]

in all cases the result is [] empty, nothing

Any tips?

I'm using python3 ubuntu12.4 and psutil 0.51

Answer (score 0):

on Linux you can go with `w`:

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> print subprocess.check_output('w')
>>> print subprocess.check_output('w').split('\n')[2:]
>>> print [s.split()[0] for s in subprocess.check_output('w').split('\n')[2:] if s]
['root']
```